# Finding Reccurring Number Combinations in Column of Numbers

Tags: mysql, vba, loops

I have searched and found discussions and solutions to similar problems, but not quite or as complex as I'm trying to figure out.

I have an access table which consists of two columns Draw Number and Number Drawn as shown below. Draw Number is repeated 20 times, to correspond to the 20 numbers that are drawn in each particular draw.

I'm trying to figure a way to determine the most frequent occurring combination of numbers (5 numbers) for all of the draws in each of the 20 number sets. So for instance, 12341 occurs n x, 12342 occurs nx, 12343 occurs n x, etc.

I've created parameter queries which allow me to search for different number combinations from 2 to 10 numbers, and they work OK returning the number of occurrences of a combination of numbers that I input through a simple UI. But the goal is to figure out pragmatically what the optimum combination of numbers.

Hope this makes sense. And by the way, there are 36 million or so rows in the table. The para queries work quite well however; it takes just over a second to return results for each number added. So, query two numbers = 2 second wait, three numbers = 3 second wait, etc.

I've been thinking about a loop of some type but don't know how to get started? Processing time isn't an issue; can take a day if required!

### This is written in VBA and has an assortment of queries, temp tables, etc to get the job done.

The text says Access, but the tags say MySql, which is it? –  RBarryYoung 21 hours ago

This part confuses me: I'm trying to figure a way to determine the most frequent occurring combination of numbers (5 numbers) for all of the draws in each of the 20 number sets. So for instance, 12341 occurs n x, 12342 occurs nx, 12343 occurs n x, etc. –  Newd 21 hours ago

### ^What do you mean five numbers? No where in your sample data do I see 12341. Please explain using the data you have, and give expected results using that data. –  McAdam331 21 hours ago

***drosberg - clarification:***
*thanks for the response. It is an Access application, but as a first-time poster Stackoverflow recommends tags?
By five numbers I mean the most frequently occurring group of five numbers (I used five as an example, could be groups of 2 to 10 numbers) which occur in each draw, where a draw consists of 20 drawn numbers from a total of 80 numbers. So the data that I posted was intended as an example. The sample provided only has 50, 51 in common. I can plug 50 and 51 into the parameter query and it will tell me that this combination occurs 60,000 times (or whatever), but perhaps 50 and 57 occurs 65,000 times.
If i was to do this manually, and assuming I'm looking for the most frequent 5 number combination I would enter the following in the parameter query: 1,2,3,4,1 group = 30,000 occurrences 1,2,3,4,2 group = 31,000 occurrences 1,2,3,4,3 group = 31,050 occurrences 1,2,3,4,4 group = 29,050 occurrences etc........... etc........... 
but I would have to do this for every combination of 5 numbers that can be derived from the numbers 1 thru 80. I'm hoping to have program do the work!!
thanks
don*

```
DRAW NUMBER NUMBER DRAWN
1   1
1   28
1   19
1   3
1   38
1   46
1   43
1   29
1   13
1   22
1   20
1   11
1   50
1   51
1   53
1   54
1   57
1   64
1   76
1   78
2   29
2   14
2   2
2   1
2   35
2   40
2   39
2   30
2   10
2   27
2   21
2   6
2   42
2   50
2   51
2   53
2   54
2   61
2   65
2   69
```

Comment: The text says Access, but the tags say MySql, which is it?

Comment: This part confuses me: `I'm trying to figure a way to determine the most frequent occurring combination of numbers (5 numbers) for all of the draws in each of the 20 number sets. So for instance, 12341 occurs n x, 12342 occurs nx, 12343 occurs n x, etc. `

Comment: ^What do you mean five numbers? No where in your sample data do I see `12341`. Please explain using the data you have, and give expected results using that data.

Comment: Hi all, just wondering if there's any additional information I can provide to help out to provide me a 'pointer' in the right direction. It is NOT critical that I figure this out, but it's been something that I've pondered off and on over the past couple of years.

Comment: Not to mention I think it's pretty cool that I'm able to work with an Access DB with 36 + million rows and get acceptable performance?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post a while ago about generating permutations with and without repetition using Excel. Perhaps you can use it.

https://michiel.wordpress.com/2015/03/29/permutations-with-repetition-using-excel/

Here's how it works. I am using strings, but you can easily modify that for numbers (since you say you need 5).

You can use the MID function to grab a single char from a string, and generate permutations from it.

[image: example of generated permutations]

=MID(Pattern,MOD([N]/[P],Length)+1,1)
N revers to the column N
P refers to the horizontal row (1,4,16). You can generate these with a formula like =4^.

After putting in the code, you can make a list of all permutations in Excel and in the cell next to it generate a sql query that you can perform as well from VBA.

Example: [Looking up Access database in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174223/looking-up-access-database-in-excel)

Or find a commercial tool like http://thingiequery.com/ 
I don't know if there's any open source tools for it.

Comment: @Artjom I added a short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that you should consider:

Say there are 100 balls.

1. Setting up a table to have one row for each "Draw number" with 100 columns one for every possible number each column has type boolean.

When you look to see which draws had number 23 you just add a 
WHERE Column23 = true.

For numbers 23 and 56
WHERE Column23 = true AND Column56 = true

This should massivel simplify and speed up your SQL.

2. You set up a table with every possible combination of numbers.
   You run SQL to find the counts.

Harvey